# Заглавная буква И в PHP

Tags: php, кириллица

Есть веб-сервер на Windows Server 2016 + IIS. PHP 7.2.7
На веб сервере есть очень простой скрипт для отправки сообщений в телеграм:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL,'ru_RU');
$update = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($update, true);

file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage?chat_id=".$data["chatid"]."&text=".$data["text"]);

?>
```

ПРоблема в том, что если в отправляемом сообщении есть заглавная буква И, то php не отправляет ответное сообщение, в логе ошибка:
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request...
Python, C# без проблем отправляют букву И :) Но в данный момент нужен PHP и очень нужна заглавная буква И :)
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём проблема? Возможно ли и как это исправить?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php и/или https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: Спасибо, работает